# Woocommerce : buy 1 get another "coming soon" products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We are working on a store and we would like to have this feature that allows customer to buy one available downloadable product and also get another downloadable products once they are available in the store.

The concept of this is like magazine subscription which subscribers will get new issue every month.

I have had a look at Woocommerce Subscriptions plugin but it is too expensive for us. We did purchase Subscriptio plugin from Codecanyon and also we purchased Woocommerce Chained products and Woocommerce Pre-orders plugin to get them work together but they didn't do the job as when we chained available product with pre-order product, the store doesn't allow the customer to proceed to download the available one.

Is there any other plugin that you recommend? 
I will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at Easy Digital Downloads and its plugin.Could you describe a bit more.I think this can help you,have a look at the extension Recurring Payments  http://docs.easydigitaldownloads.com/article/253-allow-customers-on-a-subscription-to-have-access-to-all-products

Comment: hi WisdmLabs, our website is a simple publication store. We have some publication that we usually issue once a month. Customer, who buys any issue will get the previous issues and upcoming issues from the year they purchase. Which means, if a customer purchases one of this year publications, they will get publications that were issued from Jan 2015 - now and also they will get the publications that are about to be issued from Sept - Dec 2015 automatically once they are available.

Comment: In EDD what you can do is create a single Bundled Product , Subscribers of this Bundled product will be able to download all products in that bundle. And you can then add new products to the bundle monthly or yearly. The payment too has an option of being one time like a subscription fee or monthly weekly or daily